# Is virtual machine isolated from host virus or backdoor from data protection?

Tags: security, virtual-machine, virus

I'm wondering whether it's safer to read some data inside a virtual machine in order to protect it. If I have a virus infected windows host, is it trivial for the virus to access the data I read through a linux virtual machine or is it significantly harder ?

Comment: I would say it is safer, but not 100% safe.  If the virus really wanted to, it could probably gain access to the data in a guest VM.

Answer (score 0):

The best answer anyone can give is: it depends.

Can malware on the host access a virtual machine? Sure, if it is made to do so. Can it access the virtual disks? Sure. Can it access the network traffic the VM is doing? Sure.

So after all this, is it safe? It might be. Malware usually doesn't seem to bother going to these extremes. But that doesn't mean some wouldn't try. And especially monitoring/altering network traffic might not have any separation between the host and the guest.

So please don't assume that you could safely have a VM inside a compromised host and not worry about anything. If a host is compromised, you have to assume everything is compromised.

Answer (score -2):

Nah, you can be safely assured, that the virus won't read any data unless the settings you have made so. First we need to know what software do you use for this virtual environment. I would advise using virtual box. And for your question, in virtual box, there is a setting which allows you to specify some folders on the HDD to be mounted in vd, so you can view the software present in those folders/drives. This you can set to read and write or just to read. But in both case if the virus is present in that folder then there are slim chances that it could spread inside the vd, but not much as most of the virus have their executables in the startup folder, so that they could be started automatically when windows starts, but it still depends on the type of virus, like which activates with a file or folder. There are many types, but there is also one thing to note that the viruses in windows are all executables, or windows only compatible, they would not be compatible with Linux, in which case if there is any virus, in the folder it would just show it up, which in windows case would be hidden.

So you can be 99.99% sure that there won't be any problem with using Linux in windows host, as I have myself used windows 8, in windows 7 as host, which was full of virus and malware, that even the windows defender wouldn't detect any virus, but when I used w8 in VB, there wasn't any problem in it.

Comment: No, you can't be 99.99% sure. The viruses could alter network streams, access virtual disks and do whatever it wants. And why would you use any machine "full of virus and malware" for even a second? How will that give any assurance to anyone else?

Comment: I can't show you, but I accessed files from the host machine, and I even gave then r&w rights, then I used that vd, in my friends pc in VB, and there wasn't even a trace of virus in the bit defender. As I told the windows virus, most of then can't spread to Linux, they won't be compatible, and as I said earlier the viruses tend to get into the startup folder, so that they can be executed while booting, that's why you can be assured. And as to why I use a machine file of viruses, is because I had to do some work urgently and needed some files from my c: drive, which I couldn't risk losing.

Comment: "I have a case where nothing happened" is never proof of anything else than at that one time nothing happened.

Comment: Then you could try yourself, as I said in my answer, that it depends on what type of a virus or malware or ant type of threat it is, and whether it is compatible to Linux to be spread across the machine. Also if you don't acres the files from host machine, the virus from the host won't even reach Linux. So it's a practical question, not a theortical one, that it can be explained. So toy could just try it to make it sure.

Comment: The malware has access to the system. It can access anything, including the VM disks. There is no need for the VM to access anything on the host for that to happen. And how do you suggest trying with every single virus and malware, present and future, known and unknown, to "make it sure"? There is no sure in this matter, except that there is nothing stopping malware from accessing the VM.

Comment: You couldn't even access the files present inside a virtual disk yourself without mounting it with some software, and you think that the virus would be specialised enough to do that itself, unless someone plants a backdoor in your system. It isn't 2020 yet, wait for it maybe then they would have virus spread through electricity. And phrase just leave it here, let the asker of the question report here.

Comment: So, you think that malware that can target certain software, create end points for accessing the system and stay hidden etc wouldn't be able to simply read a VM disk? It's not 1980s. And a virus can have a backdoor, or install one. It's not like the question is only about a certain type of virus.

Comment: Damn I really hate the arguing ones, and like not to argue more, but I already said that it depends on the type of virus there is, use an antivirus to detect any virus in host machine, keep your host machine clean then. Okay, for your sake, don't be 99.99% sure, assure yourself however you want. What can I say, let the one who asked thus question see this and report, and use the chart button, don't drag the chat too long, for just useless comments, although I must admit my own comments are useless. I will have to flag all the comments.